# Firebase Auth. How to design many users can login to one main company account.?

Tags: firebase, authorization, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

Hi I have used Firebase over 2years and really loveit.

I want to craete a new app for company. and use Firebase Auth.
I understand for game 1user per :  1 game record data.   It is easy. i know how to do it.

BUT enterprise app LIKE Slack.com;
many users link to one company data with own login.

```
ex ;   {{company}}.slack.com  =>  user1, user2, user3
    or www.slack.com/{{company}} =>  user1, user2, user3
    or www.slack.com  [only] =>  user1, user2, user3, [link => 1company data]
```

So it means one company account and have many users link to it with permission.

My questions are

1. Are there any best practice for company login ?
2. It is better if it can only with username login(not email login for users).

Comment: Are you asking how to verify that a user signing up for the app is from the company in question? If so, your app could verify the domain in their email is @company.com. If you are wanting to use username logins, i would think there would need to be some kind of verification email sent to an entered email address, then allow the user name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using the following paradigm:

- Decide what parts of your [Firebase] database are public and what parts are specific to each individual user
- Use Authentication to log in your enterprise users (if you are developing an app specific to your enterprise .. use eMail to verify that they are in the enterprise domain.
- Use database rules to establish permissions (e.g. proper domain login can access parts xxx; public can only access yyy; individual can access zzz)

Comment: riseres ... if you like the answer can you also award the "bounty"?

Comment: I sorry I though it automatic award the bounty. now i know how to award.